# How to add ssh User and set permission

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I have a public key (generate by puttyGen)and added the public key to  /etc/.ssh/authorized_keys. I created an Ubuntu User. But now i don't know how to link the public key with "Ubuntu User". I want the user could login via ssh with Public key.

Comment: Although you can change the configuration, the default ssh server settings are to use the users home directory `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` To set up ssh keys see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2 . Putty is available in both windows and Linux but the keys are a bit different see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-digitalocean-droplets-windows-users and https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/windows/puttygen . The public key goes on the server and you can transfer it from linux with `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: sure , ask a more specific question if you get stuck

Comment: Read `man ssh-copy-id` - it does what you seem to want.